# Label alignment with expression

Tags: equations, lyx, labels

[image][image]I am trying to add a label to an mathematical expression (under Lyx) but the alignment of it with the expression isn't right (slightly under the line of the expression) as shown in the attached picture.
Here's the code that i am using :

```
\begin{equation} \centerline{ $   \sum\limits_{s=0}^n \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \lVert \psi_{i_x,i_y;x,y}(t) \rVert ^2  =1 $ } \label{eq:eq12}    \end{equation}
```

***Preamble Code is :***

```
 % increases link area for cross-references and autoname them

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}

\addto\extrasenglish{%

\renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}

\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}

\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}

\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}

\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}

\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}

}

% in case somebody want to have the label "Equation"

%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\negthinspace\autoref{#1})}

% that links to image floats jumps to the beginning

% of the float and not to its caption

\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}



\usepackage{amsmath}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman

% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added

\let\myTOC\tableofcontents

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%

\frontmatter

\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}

\myTOC

\mainmatter }

% makes caption labels bold

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\setcapindent{1em}

% enables calculations

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{qcircuit}

\usepackage{cleveref} %for cref

\usepackage{mathtools}

% fancy page header/footer settings

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

% increases the bottom float placement fraction

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}

% avoids that floats are placed above its sections

\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}
```

Could you help me with that ?
Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

`equation`s are both already centered and in math mode. If one removes `\centerline` (this should no longer be used anyway) and the additional math mode, it works fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}  
\sum\limits_{s=0}^n \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \lVert \psi_{i_x,i_y;x,y}(t) \rVert ^2 = 1 
\label{eq:eq12}    
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(using things like equation number in `\label{eq:eq12}` is not really a good idea,  because it may change. Better choose labels that describe the equation )

---

In your preamble the packages `hyperref` and `babel` are missing and there must not be empty lines in `\addto\extrasenglish{...}`. If these errors are corrected, the following compiles and gives centred equations.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

 % increases link area for cross-references and autoname them

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}

\addto\extrasenglish{%
\renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}

% in case somebody want to have the label "Equation"

%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\negthinspace\autoref{#1})}

% that links to image floats jumps to the beginning

% of the float and not to its caption
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}

\usepackage[braket,qm]{qcircuit}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman

% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added

\let\myTOC\tableofcontents

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%

\frontmatter

\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}

\myTOC

\mainmatter }

% makes caption labels bold

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\setcapindent{1em}

% enables calculations

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{qcircuit}

\usepackage{cleveref} %for cref

\usepackage{mathtools}

% fancy page header/footer settings

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

% increases the bottom float placement fraction

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}

% avoids that floats are placed above its sections

\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}  
\sum\limits_{s=0}^n \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \lVert \psi_{i_x,i_y;x,y}(t) \rVert ^2 = 1 
\label{eq:eq12}    
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, if i remove centerline the expression is not centered, even when using mathtools package

Comment: @Joe Centered if the default. Did you change it somehow? Do you have something like `leqn` as document class option?

Comment: document class is scrbook

Comment: @Joe You mean `scrbook`? This also has centered equations by default. Can you make a short document that shows how you managed to get non-centered equations?

Comment: you mean a screenshot of the output ? i attach it in the question in a minute

Comment: @Joe No, the source code.

Comment: it's under Lyx what code do you want the one in the preamble maybe ?

Comment: @Joe I think lyx has some option to export to .tex code. This would be preferable. If this does not work, maybe the preamble will also tell the problem.

Comment: i added the code in the preamble

Comment: @Joe Can you check if it works when you fix the errors in the preamble?

Comment: it says option clash for package babel !

Comment: @Joe I'll be awk for approx half an hour

Comment: @Joe OK, remove the line with `\usepackage{babel}` again. it seems this is not your complete preamble but babel is loaded somewhere else. It would be really really helpful to have a complete compilable .tex document for testing

Comment: Thx for the endeavor, it seems like a very serious problem that i don't have time to solve it from the roots. i used \qquad to margin off the expression until in the middle ! cheers !